# Multi Select Drag And Drop In Angular 4?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, drag-and-drop

I am using [Angular 2 Drag-and-Drop](https://github.com/akserg/ng2-dnd) to select list items via drag and drop approach.
But with this, I am failing to use it in touch devices and perform multiple items drag and drop.

Is there another approach to do drag and drop with multi select? It should also work for touch devices.

Comment: Completely opinion-based, but I use [Dragula](https://bevacqua.github.io/dragula/) for that

Comment: try using primeNg components. here is the link https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/dragdrop

Answer (score 0):

you can also use [ng2-dragula](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-dragula) library for drag and drop list item and it's also work on touch devices as well as work on web.